# Remote Debug - Visual Studio Publish vs Release Management Deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, ms-release-management

I have a web app that I'm trying to debug remotely.  I'm using VS 2015.  I have the Remote Debugging tools for VS 2015 installed on the server.  I can successfully debug the app if I deploy it to the server using the VS2015 Publish function.

The problem I'm having is that I want to use a build server and remote management agent to deploy the site, but when I use this process, I am not able to remote debug the app.  When I try to debug the app, I can attach to the worker process, but I am not able to hit any breakpoints.  My breakpoint icons display like the symbol files are not loaded.  My Build definition is set to build a Debug build.  My release template is copying all files, including the .PDB files to the target server.  The .PDB files are out there, just like they are when I publish via VS2015.

Am I missing anything?  Are there any other steps I need to take when use the Build/Release Management process?  Do I have to do something else to get the symbol files to load?